# Neo4j apoc procedures impala configuration

Tags: neo4j, hive, impala

1) Downloaded the impala drivers 2.5.37 from
    https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/impala/jdbc/2-5-37.html

2) Executed:
`call apoc.load.driver("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver")`

No errors.

3) Executed:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:impala://<URL>:21050/default;user=<username>;password=<password>",
'<database>.<table name>') YIELD row
RETURN row.account as account_num
```

> Error :Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute SQL statement `SELECT *
>   FROM ..  Error:  [Simba]ImpalaJDBCDriver
>   Error setting/closing session: {0}.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `apoc.load.jdbc` must be a string that is either a table name or a SQL statement. Replace `'.'` with the appropriate value (in your case, probably the name of the table that contains the `account` column).